# How to make use of list names in accessing elements in a for loop?

Tags: r

I have a list of matrices and need to access both, the names and the matrices separately in a for-loop. I can either access the list by its elements or by its names, however, both approaches are not working for me. I have created a toy example in order to demonstrate my problems:

```
# example list construction
a <- matrix(c(1),nrow=3,ncol=3)
b <- matrix(c(2),nrow=3,ncol=3)
c <- matrix(c(3),nrow=3,ncol=3)
my_list <- list("a"=a,"b"=b, "c"=c)
```

The variables for the matrices and the names are "string-equal" as I hope to find a way to easily switch from one string role to the other (from variable to character string and back).

Is there any way, in order to access the list elements by the corresponding elements of the names-list? Here my try:

```
# 1. approach (by list names): error - argument must be an array 
for (i in names(my_list)){
  print(i)
  s<-rowSums(my_list$i)       $ why is rowSums(my_list$"a") working?
  print(s)
}
```

If not, how can I access the name of a list element in such a way that I receive an ordinary character string that is for example printable (in my real task, I need to add the character string as a colum name to another data frame)?

```
# 2. approach (by list elements): name is not printed
for (i in my_list){
  print(names(i))
  s<-rowSums(i)
  print(s)
}
```

I probably do not understand the data format of lists and the way for-loops loop through them.

Thank you!

**Follow up Question**

As Andrew Gustar wrote, a solution is to use the list-by-names approach, but use `my_list[[i]]` instead of `my_list$i`. Now I am even able to build up a new list by using the old names:

```
collect <- list()
for (i in names(my_list)){
  s<-rowSums(my_list[[i]])
  collect[[i]] <- c(s)
}
```

Is it also possible to build up `collect` as a matrix or as a data.frame?

```
collect <- c()
```

and

```
  collect[[i]] <- c(s)
```

builds up a list.

```
collect <- data.frame()
```

together with one of the following three

```
  collect[i] <- c(s)
  collect[[i]] <- c(s)
  collect$i <- c(s)
```

all return an error.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you wanna return list$a , list$b and list$c

Comment: `my_list[[i]]` should work instead of `my_list$i` in your loop

Comment: Thank you! R can be so easy if one knows what to do. I have tried `my_list[i]` which gave me an error as by `my_list[i]` I get a length 1 sublist of the list and not an element as desired. Now I am even able to build up a new list by using the old names (see my revision in the original post).